Unable to access html
I am a newbie to Hugo and am currently just playing around with a basic template to get a feeling for it. As i'm trying to integrate a javascript snippet to build a popup it seems like the script is unable to call or change my html and css.
    console.log('Am here?');

    const popup = document.getElementsByClassName('tryme')[0];
    function openPopup(){
    popup.style.display = 'block';
    console.log('Hello?');
    }

    function hello(){
    for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        console.log(i);
          }
    }  
    hello()

    console.log('Hello?');

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ or site.Language.LanguageCode site.Language.Lang }}" dir="{{ or 
    site.Language.LanguageDirection `ltr` }}">
    <head>
    {{ partial "head.html" . }}
    </head>
    <body id="body">
    <header>
    <button onclick="openPopup">OPEN</button>
    <div class="tryme"></div>
    {{ partial "header.html" . }}
    </header>
    <main>
    {{ block "main" . }}{{ end }}
    </main>
    <footer>
    {{ partial "footer.html" . }}
    </footer>
  
    </body>

    </html>

    .tryme {
      position: fixed;
      background-color: antiquewhite;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
       display: none;
    }

I have tried adding the script into the baseof.html or the main.js but got the same results either way. i have also tried to adress the html in different ways (id, class, queryselector), i have also added different print commands at different stages of the script and the ones that don't refer to any html are working fine, only the one inside the function that is supposed to change the display property of .tryme is not showing in the console.

In above snippet I dont see <script src="..." ></script>  tag being included.

the script tags are sitting inside the head partial

it wont work, because js will execute before DOM loads, means script won't be able to access html code. Solution is put it before closing tag of body. eg .... <script src="..."></script> </body></html>

have you tried using the popover api instead of creating your own? Might be worth a shot - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/popover
The dialog element may be of use also.
